# Is it possible to make "ul" corners round? I tried using "border-radius" but that did not work

Tags: html, css

HTML (only the code I have a problem with):

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
  min-width: 204px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#myMenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#DisplaySettings">DisplaySettings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#JavaScript">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried using

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

but it didn't work. I was expecting the `ul` to get round corners.

Comment: The border **is** round. Just that the border color is transparent and there's no background color for `ul` so you can't see it. The black background you are seeing is from `.dropdown-content`

Comment: Your code currently produces a blank page, because of the `position: absolute`. Please trim your code down to a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `border-radius: 10px;` to `#myMenu`. However, it seems you want to apply it to `.dropdown-content` instead.
Also, `display: none;` should be removed because this rule hides the whole content:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
  min-width: 204px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;

  border-radius: 10px;
}

#myMenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#DisplaySettings">DisplaySettings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#JavaScript">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The border-radius that you use is correct.
But you have to use a background color to the #myMenu so you can see it.

Comment: works, but i still get black corners

Comment: @MohammedAl-Hashimi  of course you do, that's the background of the parent `div` - _that_ one you did not give rounded border corners to.